# Create kmz with coordinates from images and thumbnails for symbols

Tags: google-earth, image, kmz

I have about 110 geotagged images and am looking for an effective way to create a `.kmz` which contains for each image a point based on its geotag and uses a thumbnail of the picture as symbol. Clicking on the thumbnail should - as usual - open the larger image.

I am able to manually load all images into Google Earth, but this takes a long time and I am not able to create the thumbnails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using third party software "[Geosetter](https://www.geosetter.de/)".

The software allows users to select geotagged images and export them to GoogleEarth, with several settings to choose from regarding size, style, naming etc.

Proper image naming requires some preparation, otherwise the tool is fairly easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

You can use combination of 'Google Photos' and 'Google myMaps'. Simply upload your geotagged images into Google Photos. Then open 'Google myMaps' with the same account. You should be able to create new map and layer by importing images from Photo albums. After you have created the layer. You can download the map as a KML/KMZ.

Note: the Photos must reside in google Photos for the KML file to work as the KML file  will only provide link to the photos, not embed the photo itself.

Alternatively, if you want to embed the photo itself, use the awesome tool FME to create KMZ/KML from the geotagged images. I did the same and it works great.

Comment: Since these are company pictures, I'd rather not upload them to google photos. Also, I wouldn't upload private pictures either.

Answer (score 0):

But Geosetter is unable to create kml with link to the photo, only kmz with embedded photos.
This was the best tool for this - while it was working: https://www.gearthblog.com/blog/archives/2015/11/importing-geotagged-photos-into-google-earth.html, but you can do with this as well: https://geoprocessing.online/tool/photos-to-kmz/, but it has some limitations.
I'm also looking for a free solution like Geosetter (or an online tool would be much better without uploading files) but with result of a kml with links to original photos.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/226722)