# QGIS Export to KML with image file

Tags: qgis, kml, image

I have the following:

1. a layer in QGIS
2. points
3. three columns of data
4. and an image.

When I export to .kml, via client request, it loads fine in Google Earth and shows all the points, but when I click on a point I see the file name and not the image.  I have been playing with adding a calculated field but no luck.

How do I create a field with an expression that will display the image when exported?

Comment: Could you please provide us with a screenshot. It is most probably because the path is not correct, perhaps relative path.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326372/create-kmz-with-coordinates-from-images-and-thumbnails-for-symbols

Answer (score 1):

You can install the Layer2KMZ plugin in QGIS.

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/layer2kmz/

[image]

which should save everything correctly.

Remember, that as an output you will have the .kmz file. This is a zipped .kml file, which includes all additional elements related to it. In your case, it will be the image defined I guess.

Comment: It's showing the image filename xxxx.jpg and not the image which I click on the thumbnail in google earth?

Comment: Have you tried the KMZ? It should include your image thumbnail in the zipped file.

Comment: Yes I installed the plugin created the kmz.  When I load in google earth has the info in the fields of the layer, shows the filename of the .jpg, but doesn't display the image.  If I add the following code to a new field - <img style="max-width:500px;" src="file:///C:/Users/fjpan/Documents/Pole suvey/local_file.jpg">.  It display the jpeg in the kml, but I'm trying to avoid manually doing this for every entry.

Comment: Hmm... Maybe not manually. Install Notepad ++ or Visual Studio Code. Then by following these instructions: 
http://www.mkrgeo-blog.com/bulk-text-field-name-changes-in-multitude-of-kml-files-without-programming-knowledge/
you could change the image path quickly as long as each of them is in one directory.